# Error connecting to work item repository

Tags: jbpm

I'm getting this exception when trying to connect to a custom work item repository in jBPM 6.1.0.Final workbench:

```
2015-04-15 17:03:07,712 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-24) UT005023: Exception handling request to /jbpm-console/jbpmservicerepo: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.util.Map
        at org.jbpm.process.workitem.WorkItemRepository.getWorkDefinitions(WorkItemRepository.java:38) [jbpm-flow-builder-6.1.0.Final.jar:6.1.0.Final]
        at org.jbpm.designer.web.server.JbpmServiceRepositoryServlet.doPost(JbpmServiceRepositoryServlet.java:110) [jbpm-designer-backend-6.1.0.Final.jar:6.1.0.Final]
```

The wid file causing this error is:

```
import org.drools.core.process.core.datatype.impl.type.StringDataType;

[ 
    [
        "name" : "CustomWorkItem",
        "description" : "Custom Work Item description",
        "parameters" : [],
        "results" : [
            "result_out" : new StringDataType(),
        ],
        "displayName" : "Custom Work Item",
        "icon" : "defaultservicenodeicon.png",
        "category" : "Service",
        "defaultHandler" : "com.example.CustomWorkItemHandler",
        "dependencies" : []
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception is caused by the empty `parameters` part in the wid file, as we can see in [jbpm-flow-builder sources](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm/blob/6636cb1fd8c9c3ac4c3d66031b4fb8dc9d9f0a35/jbpm-flow-builder/src/main/java/org/jbpm/process/workitem/WorkItemRepository.java#L38):

```
            Map<String, DataType> parameterMap = (Map<String, DataType>) workDefinitionMap.get("parameters");
            if (parameterMap != null) {
                for (Map.Entry<String, DataType> entry : parameterMap.entrySet()) {
                    parameters.add(new ParameterDefinitionImpl(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
                }
            }
```

Removing the empty `parameters` part workbench will load the repository:

```
import org.drools.core.process.core.datatype.impl.type.StringDataType;

[ 
    [
        "name" : "CustomWorkItem",
        "description" : "Custom Work Item description",
        "results" : [
            "result_out" : new StringDataType(),
        ],
        "displayName" : "Custom Work Item",
        "icon" : "defaultservicenodeicon.png",
        "category" : "Service",
        "defaultHandler" : "com.example.CustomWorkItemHandler",
        "dependencies" : []
    ]
]
```